# How do i send a SSL email in Jmail?

Tags: ssl, vb6, jmail

Everyone I am using vb6 to send out emails.  I have come across a situation where i need to send it Secured via Jmail.
How do i send a SSL email in Jmail?

Here is my current code,  I need it to work with SSL as well.

```
 Set objEmail = CreateObject("JMail.Message")
 With objEmail
   .From = gcFromAddress
   .FromName = gcFromAddress
   .AddRecipient cEmailAddress

  .Subject = "" & mrsReportData("SubdivisionName").Value
  End With


objEmail.Send (gcSMTPServerAddress & ":" & gcSMTPServerPort)
```

Comment: I would really love some help on this ;)

Comment: Care to post a link to Jmail? There seem to be multiple products with that name.

Comment: It would be helpful if you supplied a better reference than "Jmail" as there are several products with that name.  Even better would be a reference to any docs and what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

Use .net for that is very easy

First create dll proyect in .net example here (http://jumbloid.blogspot.com/2009/12/making-net-dll-com-visible.html)

second use it in vb6

Comment: This answer doesn't really make sense to the question.

Comment: upss yeah, sorry. But maybe use wrapper of smtpclient have sense here example with ssl http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.enablessl.aspx. good luck

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what JMail is, however, here's code for sending mail per SSL from VB:

http://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=71899&lngWId=1

A quick check of the code however has shown it is quite buggy. Maybe however it is a good hint how to implement.